# What does "to “Pomp and Circumstance” mean here"

Tags: meaning-in-context

> New recruits offered shots of vodka during hiring interviews and offered $2,000 to quit after their first round of training (Chafkin, 2009).
>
> The 95 percent who turn down the $2,000 graduate in full ceremony to “Pomp and
>   Circumstance” in front of families and members of their new, nontraditional departments:
>
> “Each department has its own décor, ranging from the rain forest–themed to Elvis-themed, and employees are encouraged to decorate their work spaces . . .”(Rogers-Kante, 2011.)

Source: https://books.google.com.vn/books?id=lCAlDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA240&lpg=PA240&dq=The+95+percent+who+turn+down+the+$2,000+graduate+in+full+ceremony+to%E2%80%9CPomp+and+Circumstance%E2%80%9Din+front+of+families+and+members+of+their+new,+nontraditional+departments:&source=bl&ots=uRuX4dnBL-&sig=ACfU3U2UdIORKjOMN9spn-MLBqKoXzAYBA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjIu6uZ2r_hAhVEE4gKHTJUBloQ6AEwAHoECAgQAQ#v=onepage&q=The%2095%20percent%20who%20turn%20down%20the%20%242%2C000%20graduate%20in%20full%20ceremony%20to%E2%80%9CPomp%20and%20Circumstance%E2%80%9Din%20front%20of%20families%20and%20members%20of%20their%20new%2C%20nontraditional%20departments%3A&f=false

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Pomp and Circumstance Marches](http://Pomp%20and%20Circumstance%20Marches) are a set of orchestral music compositions by the English composer Sir Edward Elgar.  The middle section of march number one is traditionally played as a processional march during formal graduation ceremonies (you can hear it at the Wikipedia article I've linked above), and North Americans are used to calling just this one section "Pomp and Circumstance."  It is capable of being "looped" - that is, played over and over again without pause - so it can be used for processions of any length.

At least in North America, it is used so frequently at graduations that movies and TV shows (and books, as you've quoted) use it to set the mood of a formal graduation.

The phrase "pomp and circumstance" itself comes from the play "Othello" by William Shakespeare and is frequently used to describe a very serious, important ceremony.

---

Edited to add more explanation:

When we use the word **to** followed by the name (or description) of a piece a music, then it means "accompanied by" or "while [piece of music] is playing."

> The bride and groom danced **to** the song "My Girl."

So the quoted phrase "[they] graduate in full ceremony to 'Pomp and Circumstance'" could be paraphrased as:

> [They] have a very formal graduation ceremony, accompanied by the traditional graduation music called "Pomp and Circumstance."

Comment: The term "Pomp and circumstance" existed before the composition you name.

Comment: @Astralbee - Yes, it's from Shakespeare.  But the context it's being used in refers specifically to the musical composition. I can add the history of the term.

Answer (score 0):

Pomp and circumstance is a term coined by William Shakespeare in his play *Othello* and has been used throughout the ages to describe *a very formal celebration*, with lots of *ceremony*.

It is *also* the title of a composition by Elgar and his music may well be used at such grandiose ceremonies; however, an occasion does not require music of any kind to be described as having "pomp and circumstance". According to [this](https://grammarist.com/phrase/pomp-and-circumstance/) grammar resource, the term is used mainly the USA to describe graduation ceremonies where the Elgar composition is *often* played, however other pieces of ceremonial music may equally be played.

In modern English the term is sometimes used to describe something that is *overly-elaborate* and is excessively ceremonial.

Comment: It is clear from the fact that the excerpt says "in full ceremony **to** 'Pomp and Circumstance'" (instead of "**with** pomp and circumstance"), that the musical composition is being specifically referenced.

Comment: @CanadianYankee Agreed, but I have added a link that shows the term is also used where *alternative* ceremonial music is played.